# AngularJS:how to disable all the form controls in a form?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to disable all the form components so that it can't be edited when view button is clicked.
this is my form

```
<form action="#" class="form-horizontal" >
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="fieldname" class="col-md-3 control-label">Name</label>
      <div class="col-md-6">
         <input type="text" ng-model="newItem.customSelected" typeahead="name as name.name for name in members | filter:{name:$viewValue}" class="form-control" />
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="fieldhname" class="col-md-3 control-label">House name</label>
      <div class="col-md-6">
         <input type="text" ng-model="newItem.customSelected1" typeahead="house_name as house_name.house_name for house_name in family | filter:{house_name:$viewValue}" class="form-control" />
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="" class="col-md-3 control-label"><?php echo $this->lang->line('label_family_id'); ?></label>
      <div class="col-md-6">
         <input type="text" ng-model="newItem.customSelected2" typeahead="fm as fm.family_reg_no for fm in family | filter:{family_reg_no:$viewValue}" class="form-control" />
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3"></div>

</form>
```

and this is my button

```
<input type="button" class="finish btn-success btn" ng-click="view(newItem)" value="view"/>
```

Comment: [Duplicate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21638079/angularjs-disabling-all-form-controls-between-submit-and-server-response) This question came first, but the other question produced more discussion. Both discussions agree that a `<fieldset ng-disabled="...">` is the answer (both have that same answer **twice**!) Moreover, both discussions acknowledge not all browsers support disabled fieldset; IE may not work.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Rather than handling it at per-field level, you can put all form elements into fieldset and use ng-disabled to disable the whole fieldset.

Comment: This doesn't work in IE at all.  It actually disables validation on elements.

Comment: Does not work for Dropdown

Comment: better you give a part of sample code

Answer (score 18):

you can use `fieldset` tag by surrounding your buttons with a `fieldset` and using `ng-disabled` attribute:

```
<form action="#" class="form-horizontal" >
   <fieldset ng-disabled="isClicked">
      <!--your form here --!>
   </fieldset>
</form>
```

now all that left is in the `view(newItem)` function do:

```
$scope.view = function(newItem){
   $scope.isClicked = true;
   // Your code here and set it to false when your are done with it
}
```

Comment: fieldset is not supported in ie 9 if that matters

Answer (score 4):

You could use an overlay and have a ng-show on it or you could add to each input ng-disabled

Answer (score 4):

1. Set a scope variable when the view button is clicked.
2. Use `ng-disabled` in combination with the scope variable to disable the fields.