# How to invalidate a form in angularjs? (or how to disable a form in angularjs?)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to preven form submission for a specific user type, preferably without having to edit something in the controller and without using an any type input-field? So basically something like this:

```
<form>
  <div class ="alert" 
       ng-if="user.type='not-allowed'" 
       maybe-an-invalidate-directive>
      <p>No! Don't!</p>

      <!-- or something like this ??? -->
      <input type ="hidden" 
             required
             ng-model="'false'">
  </div>
 .... 
</form>
```

While the first one should be definately possible, I would be happy to hear about a more straightforward solution.

**EDIT:**

After thinking about it for a while, I figured that what I want to do, is not making the form invalid, but to disable it. For [a solution see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21638079/angularjs-disabling-all-form-controls-between-submit-and-server-response).

Comment: If you downvote, please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ng-submit` directive on your form element, and have it return false if you don't want it to submit.

```
<form ng-submit="user.type !== 'not-allowed' && controller.function()">
```

Comment: Interesting! How would I use it in conjunction with a submit function on ng-submit, e.g. ```<form ng-submit="user.type !== 'not-allowed; submit()'">```

Comment: Updated my answer. If first expression is false, `controller.function` won't be called.

Comment: Don't mind the downvoters, I like your answer! Almost exactly what I was looking for.